# Add HTTP header details in SOAP Request

Tags: xslt, soap, http-headers

I need to add 2 HTPP POST header details as below,

Auth-Token:xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx

Content-Type:application/soap+xml;action=http://abc

I have been searching and trying with XSLT but it is not working.
Please provide inputs on how to add HTTP POST header using XSLT.

Cheers,
Giri

Comment: You write you need to replace something in a WSDL, but you post code of a Soap message. It would help if you would post input XML and expected output.